# Kibana Discover: filter errors, exceptions

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, syslog, kibana-4, elasticsearch-2.0

I'm using Kibana Discover for filtering messages with different Severity levels.

According to RFC-3164 it may be done using formula:

```
i * 8 + <severity_level> = syslog_pri
```

Using this information I can filter `errors` with `severity_level=3` using something like this:

```
# Here is some Python code to extract list of PRI's for errors:
[i*8 + 3 for i in range(24)]
```

`syslog_pri: in (3, 11, 19, 27,...)`

The question is: How to check `IN` condition in Kibana's search string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax from Kibana search bar should be the same as the one from [`query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html). Something like the following should work:

`syslog_pri: (3 OR 11 OR 19 OR...)`

Comment: I've tried this, but it works too slow. Is there any other way?

Comment: No, there's no other way. That's the only one that is slow? You might have other issues: with the ES cluster, with how many indices (time period used) are you searching, hardware resources on the ES cluster... How many values are you searching?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using just this condition. Is it possible to search by `syslog_pri` and `@timestamp` together?

Comment: You are better if you choose the time period from the top right corner in Kibana to do this. Also, this works if `@timestamp` is chosen as the time field for the indices pattern you defined.

Comment: But generally, is it possible to find by a separate fields from search string?

Comment: `syslog_pri: (3 OR 11 OR 19 OR...) AND some_field: some_value`

Comment: Btw, I have this message: `syslog_timestamp:
    May 26 16:37:11 message: <34>May ` and query: `syslog_pri: (2 OR 10 OR 18 OR 26 OR 34 OR 42 OR 50 OR 58 OR 66 OR 74 OR 82 OR 90 OR 98 OR 106 OR 114 OR 122 OR 130 OR 138 OR 146 OR 154 OR 162 OR 170 OR 178 OR 186)`. But query also catch `26` from today's date. It's not expected for me.

Comment: But that document with that date does also have syslog_pri value that matches the query?

Comment: Not sure if all of them has, but this one has.